# JavaScript/VBScript SQL Database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I need information on JavaScript/VBScript with SQL database. I'm currently doing scripting. **My problem is, in scripting, how to connect and insert some data to a MySQL database.**

I did find something mentioning on client/server side database. Do I need to consider that also? I'm not building the application for the Web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a VBScript sample using a DSN and DSNless connection:

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/ASP/database_connection_to_MySQL.php

The sample is using ASP but ASP on the server side (everything inside the `<% %>`) is VBScript.

Comment: Yes thank you..the tutorial helps alot. i did try running the programs, i got no problem with DNS, but without DNS, i dont know how to get this one: ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=Status.mdf; " &_ "UID=mysql_username;PASSWORD=mysql_password; OPTION=3". What is the Driver, UID, Password. if i dont have those, how to assign as empty? thanks. – unknown (google) 0 secs ago

Comment: The driver is the name/description of the way you are connectioning to MySQL.  You have to have a driver to connect.  Likely when you installed MySQL on your box it installed some default drivers and ODBC 3.51 is likely the default driver (don't know that for sure).

Comment: For username & password if MySQL can connect without them (which I'm not sure it can, don't know enough about MySQL to say for sure) you would simply delete those from the string.

Comment: how n where can i find this default driver? I have SQL Server 2005 installed in my machine. thx

Comment: I thought you were using MySQL?  The drivers installed on your machine can be found under Administrative Tools, Data Sources (ODBC).  There's a tab called drivers.  These are what are installed on your PC.  Here's a link to a site that has references to connection strings for various DB's.  http://www.connectionstrings.com/  It can come in handy to help you get the right connection string.

Comment: hmm...MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server is not the same? i thought both using sql queries?? Correct me if im wrong..! thx

Comment: still having problem..even i try to look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005 but still cannot figure out what to put..please i'm really stuck!

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert data into a MySQL database you would need to have some type of application layer running on the server (PHP, Ruby on Rails, [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), whatever).

You should work with the people that are building the application side web services to get this sorted out.

Comment: Yes thank you..the tutorial helps alot. i did try running the programs, i got no problem with DNS, but without DNS, i dont know how to get this one: ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=Status.mdf; " &_
"UID=mysql_username;PASSWORD=mysql_password; OPTION=3". What is the Driver, UID, Password. if i dont have those, how to assign as empty? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [WSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)? Try using [ADO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX_Data_Objects) and the solution provided by klabranche.

Comment: Yes, for now using WSH. Thanks to response from klabranche, i can connect using access database. But i wanna using MySQL database instead.Now got problem/errors on how to get/assign the connection string. Are you also using WSH? Any good tutorial using WSH? thx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

Finally I have found the solution to my problems. I post my answers here, hopefully can benefit anyone out there. For scripting I'm using VBScript, [WSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host).

I choose this connection from this site: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

**Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance**

```
Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

*From Control Panel Administrative Tools, Data Sources (ODBC), driver tab, I found my provider here. My server I take from C#, e.g. Data Source.*

```
//Create connection using VBScript.
ConnString = "Provider=SQLNCLI; SERVER=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=F:\Admin.mdf;Database=Admin.mdf; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

*I'm using references from C# languages:*

```
//Create connection using C#.
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=F:\Test2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```